# Developing with django on Ubuntu

Tags: django

I started developing application with Django on Ubuntu.
I am using Apache 2.2. with mod_wsgi for development.
Do I need to run a "touch app.wsgi" command from the terminal EVERY time I modify my script? Seems very uncomfortable :/

Am i missing something?

Meir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're developing you can/should use the built in Django webserver:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This will reload files when they change - and make it easy for you to debug your application from IDEs such as Eclipse or ERIC.

That said, there are techniques you can use to tell Apache to reload when files are changed.  These are documented here:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode